# Create a terminal style selection engine in JS used as simple selection method

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I would like to create a terminal style input method that would allow users to type dir or get and execute a series of commands I specify. In function it would be similar to a select menu where the selected/executed choice takes you to the page you want.

I've investigated plugins such as http://terminal.jcubic.pl/ but this is more robust than I need. I essentially want the look of a terminal but would like to be able to execute certain commands on a per page basis. Such as look, run, walk. Similar to the classic Space Quest Kings Quest Games or in the last two decades subservient chicken. This is essentially a tip of the hat to the retro factor.

I am at a bit of a loss of where to start and would greatly appreciate any help or direction you all could provide.

Comment: Take a look at how Microsoft's Visual Studio does intellisensing. You start typing a known command and it offers to finish the command. Then you type a dot and all the options that go with that command are presented and you can again start typing an option and it offers to finish the option. This kind of 1-step-ahead parser would be trivial to code and you could wrap this simple command parser a "retro terminal" looking interface...that's my 2-cents.

Comment: @markE I am familiar with this. I had never thought of this. I could then easily fake it with an select menu with a search. Interesting. Thanks for the idea!